# Binance ccxt fetch ohlcv exceeding 1000 limit

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

Trying to create a loop that will get  all 5m interval ohlcv data for coins in `pair_list` between start and date (3 months)

Based on some discussions and snippets I've come up with the following, however, it doesn't work

```
import ccxt
import config
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)


import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import numpy as np
#np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True)

from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time

import datetime as dt

import datedelta
import calendar
import dateutil.relativedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


start = str(int(dt.datetime(2021, 5, 1).replace(hour=1).timestamp() * 1000))
end = str(int(dt.datetime(2021, 2, 1).replace(hour=1).timestamp() * 1000))

for i in pair_list:

    startDate = end
    while startDate>start:

        bars[i] = 'exchange.fetch_ohlcv(binancePair[i], timeframe=timeframe, '
        if startDate is not None:
            bars[i] += 'since='+ str(startDate) +', limit=1000'
            d2[i] = pd.DataFrame(bars[i][:-1], columns =['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 
            'volume' ])
            d[i] = pd.concat([d2[i], d[i]], axis=0, ignore_index=True, keys=None)
            startDate[i] = d[i].timestamp[0] 

            d[i].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)   
            d[i]['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(d[i]['timestamp'], unit='ms')
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the answer you are looking for, but it will definitely solve your problem (ccxt):

```
    limit=None
```

Code would look something like this(ccxt):

```
    start_date = int(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 20).timestamp() * 1000)
    candles = exchange.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USDT', timeframe='1d', since=start_date, 2012', limit=None)
```

That should get candles to present time, then you could easily amend pandas df.

I know the Binance exchange documents state 1000 limit, though when using their api they still allow large amounts of data, for instance this code works on Binance (binance api):

```
    candles = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, "1 Jan, 2018", "22 May, 2021")
```

I know what you want to do specifically, as some exchanges do need the limit.  Though the Binance exchange those code snippets will work.

I'll make time in a few days to answer the original question, until then i hope this helps.

Comment: Hm.. I can't get more than 1000 candles from a single request. Tried ```limit=None```, ```limit=1500```, etc. If the value is not between 1 & 1000, it defaults to 500.